# Unity3d and Windows 8 run game in frame

Tags: unity, windows-8, screen-management

How do I set Unity3D to run my game on Windows 8 in a fixed size frame (with a border around it) and not in fullscreen?

I tried setting this in the Unity script and in the final C# project, but nothings seems to work.

I have set the players resolution to 1366x786 (the desired size) and while this works fine with the webplayer the windows 8 solution seems really unimpressed by it. I also tinkered with the 'Default Is Full Screen' option

Comment: Maybe you can include details about the settings you've tried so they're not suggested again here.

Comment: I've tried to research this a little further but it would help if we knew _why_ you wanted to have the one resolution regardless of monitor.. Is it simply the aspect ratio you like or must it be fixed to 1366x786 even on a 2560x1440 monitor?

Comment: Both is interesting, but at the moment I am looking for fixed 1366x786. Just like you got a game windows with this fixed size and then a floating border around it, which fills the rest

Comment: Is this for a windows 8 store app or a desktop app?

Answer (score 1):

I run Windows 8.1. Just check `Windowed` under the `Graphics` tab in the configuration when the game starts up:

[image]

---

If you don't have the startup config dialog. Go to `Edit->Project Settings->Player` and set `Display Resolution Dialog` to `Enabled`:

[image]

---

If you do not want to have the config dialog you can set the [`Screen.fullScreen`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-fullScreen.html) property to `false` in code.

Answer (score 0):

You have checked the player settings, right?

http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/class-PlayerSettings.html

Comment: Yep tried this, see the edit I made to the question